# Java 3 Hashing Programme

Tags: hash

The directions in this section of code are giving me trouble and I don't know how to follow through with them properly. (We have to write code where there are dollar signs.)

**Instructions**: write a code that repetitively invokes the HashPerformanceClass mainDriver. Then the repetitive code starts the number of insertions at statrInsertions, increase the insert count by the deltaInsertions until end insertions value.

**Problem**

I am having trouble repetitively invoking the HashPerformanceClass mainDriver, and I don't know what to do. If anyone has any advise I would be grateful.

```
public class MainClass {

    static int displayResultsNo = 0;
    void displayHashResults() {

       displayResultsNo++;

       System.out.println("\nDisplay No. - "+displayResultsNo);
       System.out.println("\n\nHash Instrumented Performance:\n-----------------------------");
       System.out.println("Trials: "           + HashPerformanceClass.trials        + ", " +
                          "Insert Count: "     + HashPerformanceClass.insertCount   + ", " +
                          "Load: "             + HashPerformanceClass.payload       + ", " +
                          "Table Start Size: " + HashPerformanceClass.startingSize);

       System.out.println("\nLinear Hashing:");
       System.out.println("Insertion  Total   Probes: " + HashPerformanceClass.insertionLinearProbes)   ;
       System.out.println("Insertion  Average Probes: " + HashPerformanceClass.insertionLinearProbesAvg);

       System.out.println("\nDouble Hashing:");
       System.out.println("Insertion  Total   Probes: " + HashPerformanceClass.insertionDoubleProbes)   ;
       System.out.println("Insertion  Average Probes: " + HashPerformanceClass.insertionDoubleProbesAvg);

       System.out.println("\nPerfect Hashing:");
       System.out.println("Insertion  Total   Probes: " + HashPerformanceClass.insertionPerfectProbes)   ;
       System.out.println("Insertion  Average Probes: " + HashPerformanceClass.insertionPerfectProbesAvg);

    }//displayHashResults()

    static int displayNo = 0;
    void displayHashAvgProbesTable(int trials, int startInsertions, int endInsertions, int deltaInsertions, double load, int startSize) {

        displayNo++;

        System.out.println("\n\nDisplay No. - "+displayNo);
        System.out.println("\nAverage Number of Probes Table \n------------------------------\ntrials: "+trials+"  Load: "+load+"  Start Size: "+startSize+"\n");
        System.out.println(String.format("%-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s", "No Of Items","Linear Hash"  ,"Double Hash"  ,"Perfect Hash ") );
        System.out.println(String.format("%-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s", "Inserted"   ,"Probe Average","Probe Average","Probe Average") );
        System.out.println(String.format("%-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s", "-----------","-------------","-------------","-------------") );

        //$ write a code that repetitively invokes the HashPerformanceClass mainDriver 
        // The the repetitive code starts the number of insertions at startInsertions, increases the insert count by the deltaInsertions
        //until end insertions value


    }//displayHashAvgProbesTable()

    MainClass () {

        //$Invoke HashPerformanceClass mainDriver using arguments of insertCount=1, trials =10, payLoad=100%, Starting Size =7, display results
        HashPerformanceClass.mainDriver(  1,    1, 1.0,    7); displayHashResults();
        HashPerformanceClass.mainDriver(100,   80, 0.5,  101); displayHashResults();   //third column 1.0 = 100%
        HashPerformanceClass.mainDriver(100,   80, 0.9,  101); displayHashResults();
        HashPerformanceClass.mainDriver( 20, 1000, 0.5,  503); displayHashResults();
        HashPerformanceClass.mainDriver( 20, 1000, 1.0, 1009); displayHashResults();
        HashPerformanceClass.mainDriver( 20, 1000, 1.0, 4999); displayHashResults();
        HashPerformanceClass.mainDriver(100, 2400, 0.5, 4999); displayHashResults();


        displayHashAvgProbesTable      ( 10, 100, 2000,  100, 0.5, 1009);
        displayHashAvgProbesTable      ( 10, 100, 2500, 1000, 0.5, 4999);
        displayHashAvgProbesTable      ( 10, 100, 2500, 1000, 0.5, 4999);

    }//MainClass

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainClass();    
    }//main()


}//MainClass
    ___________________________________________________________

 import java.util.*;

/**
 * A class for generating statistical information hash table insertion.
 */

public class HashPerformanceClass {

    static int   insertionLinearProbes    = 0, insertionDoubleProbes   =  0, insertionPerfectProbes    = 0;
    static float insertionLinearProbesAvg = 0, insertionDoubleProbesAvg = 0, insertionPerfectProbesAvg = 0;

    static int    trials;
    static int    insertCount;
    static double payload; 
    static int    startingSize;

    public static void mainDriver(int trials, int insertCount, double payLoad, int startingSize) {

        HashPerformanceClass.trials      = trials;
        HashPerformanceClass.insertCount = insertCount; 
        HashPerformanceClass.payload     = payLoad; 
        HashPerformanceClass.startingSize= startingSize;

        insertionLinearProbes    = insertionDoubleProbes     = insertionPerfectProbes    = 0;
        insertionLinearProbesAvg = insertionDoubleProbesAvg  = insertionPerfectProbesAvg = 0;

        //$ Declare all 3 hash table objects (linear, double, perfect) using the generic parameterized types as String and setting Starting Size from the mainDriver input parameter  
        DictionaryInstrumentedLinearImplementation <String, String>  linearHashTableObj; 
        DictionaryInstrumentedDoubleImplementation <String, String>  doubleHashTableObj; 
        DictionaryInstrumentedPerfectImplementation<String, String>  perfectHashTableObj;

        //Array used to hold random data inserted 
        String dataArray[];

        //$
        //For each trial set the inputs for the hash table Implementation
        // Generate the Random Data array using insert count, do only once for each trial so that all hash table types have same source data set

        //  For all 3 hash table types
        //    Instantiate new hash table object
        //    Set the pay load factor hashtableobject.set payload
        //    Insert all the data from the array into the table   insertalldata( , );
        //    Reset the probe counters for the hash table  insertionlinear probes +=
        //    Sum up the probe statistics
        //do this for all insertionlinearprobes double and perfect . . . 

        //$ Calculate all the insertion probes averages into the class variables for each hash type 

    }//mainDriver()

    /* Generate an array of random of pseudo words.  Each word will be composed of three randomly chosen syllables.
     * @param   arraySize    The number of strings to generate.
     * @return          The array of strings.
     */
    private static String[] generateRandomData(int arraySize) {
        String uniqueWordStringArray[] = new String[arraySize];
        DictionaryInstrumentedLinearImplementation<String,String> checkTable = new DictionaryInstrumentedLinearImplementation<String,String>();

        String firstSylStringArray [] = {"ther", "fal", "sol", "cal", "com",   "don", "gan", "tel", "fren", "ras", "tar", "men", "tri", "cap", "har"};
        String secondSylStringArray[] = {"mo",   "ta",  "ra",  "te",  "bo",    "bi",  "du",  "ca",  "dan", "sen", "di",   "no",  "fe",  "mi",  "so" };
        String thirdSylStringArray [] = {"tion", "ral", "tal", "ly",  "nance", "tor", "ing", "ger", "ten", "ful", "son",  "dar", "der", "den", "ton"};

        Random generator = new Random();

        int i=0;
        while (i < arraySize) {
            String valueString;
            valueString  = firstSylStringArray [generator.nextInt( firstSylStringArray.length) ];
            valueString += secondSylStringArray[generator.nextInt(secondSylStringArray.length) ];
            valueString += thirdSylStringArray [generator.nextInt( thirdSylStringArray.length) ];
            if (!checkTable.contains(valueString)) {
                // Have not seen pseudo word string before, so add it to the list array list
                uniqueWordStringArray[i] = valueString;
                checkTable.add(valueString,valueString);
                i++;
            }//end if
        }//while 
        return uniqueWordStringArray;
    }

    /* Insert all of the values in the array into the hash table. 
     * @param   dict The dictionary to insert all the words into.
     */
    private static void insertAllData(DictionaryInterface<String,String> dict, String[] dataArray) {        
        for (String wordString : dataArray) {
            dict.add(wordString, wordString);
        }
    }//insertAllData()

 }//HashPerformanceClass
```